# boot-repair has a syntax error and did not fix Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I had ubuntu working just fine. Installed Windows, and wanted to fix grub and add dual boot.

Steps taken:

1. Followed recommended steps on boot-repair.
2. [First Error Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SGN6Q2jmKN/)
3. [Second Error Summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n5T3TNJdjK/)

Any help is appreciated. When i boot through my 18.04 installation, it loads up grub rescue prompt.

Comment: You have both Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, but an old grub installed in MBR. Make sure you only boot in UEFI mode as BIOS boot will load invalid grub. Error seem to be related to flash drive, so not critical. What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: i see. Yes, i did boot it up in EFI mode, and it correctly boots into both linux and windows. System is a PC, have a nvidia 980 ti.

Comment: Any idea how to re-install a new grub?

Comment: Boot-Repair is often the easiest way to reinstall grub. In advanced options you can choose an install and drive to install grub into, do not choose partition, but with UEFI it normally just installs to first ESP, often sda's ESP. But if you have nVidia, then you need nomodeset to boot, until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it